# acer chromebook 14 keyboard issues, trackpad issues

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, chromebook

Im using an acer chromebook 14, and used a live-usb to boot ubuntu 16.04. I installed onto a 128gb spare 3.0 drive. When booted, the laptop keyboard does not work but a usb keyboard does. Also, trackpad must be pressed with much more intensity than on chromeOS. Thanks for anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am also running using a acer chromebook 14 running from a 128 gb thumb drive. I have not found a fix for the keyboard but you can fix the touchpad issue by going into your startup applications menu and adding the command

```
    xinput set-prop "Elan Touchpad" "Synaptics Finger" aa bb cc
```

and rebooting.